# What is Ambipolar Diffusion in a plasma?

Tags: plasma-physics, diffusion

I understood the mathematical derivation from the text book. But I am having hard time imagining the phenomenon physically. Can someone please explain it to me in layman's term (or in terms of some thought experiment)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most plasmas, the positive and negative species have different masses. At thermal equilibrium, this means that the mean velocity of positive charges is different than the mean velocity of negative charges. So when a plasma expands into an empty space, the species that moves faster diffuses first. As it moves outward, it creates an electric field (due to the absence of the other charge species) that "pulls along" the heavier species. This electric-field pulling couples the diffusion rates of the two species; if the pull is strong enough, then the diffusion rates become essentially equal despite the large difference in average speeds.

Comment: Is this "equal" diffusion rate called ambipolar diffusion?

Comment: @BahauddinOmar Not always. Ambipolar diffusion in general refers to the _coupling_ of diffusion rates (i.e. where one depends on the other). Equality only happens in the event of very strong coupling relative to other factors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I accepted the answer.
If possible, can you add something in case of what'd happen in the presence of a uniform magnetic field?

Comment: For magnetized fusion plasma in toroidal configurations, what matters for diffusion across the magnetic field (so-called neoclassical diffusion) is not only the thermal speed but also the ratio of charge to mass for the particles; and there it is typically the case that heavy particles (ions) tend to diffuse faster than light particles (electrons), so the electric field is set up to "pull along" the lighter species.